# .htaccess rewrite and subdomains

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a subdomain setup as onlinedev.domain.com
I need to use htaccess to rewrite to domain.com/online_content, while still showing onlinedev.domain.com in the address bar (SSL is for onlinedev.domain.com).
this is what I currently have that is very close:

```
php_flag display_errors off

RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} onlinedev\.domain\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}<->%{REQUEST_URI} ^(www\.)?([^.]+).*<->/([^/]+) [NC] 
RewriteCond %2<->%3 !^(.*)<->\1$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.+) /%2/$1 [L]
```

This correctly rewrites to domain.com/onlinedev, but if I try to change the RewriteRule to:

```
RewriteRule ^(.+) /online_content/$1 [L]
```

I get an error

I understand that there are typically better ways to do this subdomain work, but without getting into server config and DNS details, I need to do it with htaccess.

And yes, I do need to rewrite to a directory that has a different name than the subdomain.

Comment: Which error are you facing? Does the server starts but is not correctly directed or is this a config error? Cheers,
CaioToOn!

Comment: I get the following error:
Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Thanks,
   Josh

Comment: So please, try to start the server again. Then look at the apache/logs/error.log file. Look at the end of the file and post which error you're having.

Comment: This is the error:

[Tue Dec 22 10:15:01 2009] [error] [client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://onlinedev.domain.com/

So, it looks like it is redirecting to much...maybe I need to check to make sure that the rewrite has not already happened? I'm not sure how I would do that though.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I figured it out.
The issue was that I was causing an infinite loop.
Once the rewrite had happened, it was still trying to rewrite to the directory.
Here is my new htaccess that took care of it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} onlinedev\\.domain\\.com$ [NC] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/online_content/
RewriteRule ^(.+) /online_content/$1 [L]
```

Notice that I added a check to make sure that the REQUEST_URI is not the name of the directory I am rewriting to.

Answer (score 0):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =onlinedev.example.com [NC]
RewriteCond $0 !^online_content/
RewriteRule .+ /online_content/$0 [L]
```